# Calling a method with an arg of Class<T> where T is a parameterized type

Tags: java, generics

I'm attempting to call a constructor method that looks like:

```
public static SomeWrapper<T> method(Class<T> arg);
```

When T is an unparameterized type like String or Integer, calling is straightforward:

```
SomeWrapper<String> wrapper = method(String.class);
```

Things get tricky when T is a parameterized type like `List<String>`.  The following is not valid:

```
SomeWrapper<List<String>> wrapper = method(List<String>.class);
```

About the only thing I could come up with is:

```
List<String> o = new ArrayList<String>();
Class<List<String>> c = (Class<List<String>>) o.getClass();
SomeWrapper<List<String>> wrapper = method(c);
```

Surely there is an easier way that doesn't require the construction of an additional object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following syntax was suggested on the [Mockito issues discussion](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=161) board:

```
SomeWrapper<List<Foo>> wrapper = (SomeWrapper<List<Foo>>) (Object) method(List.class);
```

Answer (score 6):

No there isn't. There is no `Class` for `List<String>`, only `List`.

See [Why is there no class literal for concrete parameterized types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Why%20is%20there%20no%20class%20literal%20for%20the%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?):

> ***Because parameterized type has no exact runtime type representation.***
>
> A class literal denotes a `Class`
>   object that represents a given type.
>   For instance, the class literal
>   `String.class` denotes the `Class`
>   object that represents the type
>   `String` and is identical to the
>   `Class` object that is returned when
>   method `getClass` is invoked on a
>   `String` object. A class literal can
>   be used for runtime type checks and
>   for reflection.
>
> Parameterized types lose their type
>   arguments when they are translated to
>   byte code during compilation in a
>   process called type erasure . As a
>   side effect of type erasure, all 
>   instantiations of a generic type share
>   the same runtime representation,
>   namely that of the corresponding raw
>   type .  In other words, parameterized
>   types do not have type representation
>   of their own. Consequently, there is
>   no point in forming class literals
>   such as `List<String>.class`,
>   `List<Long>.class` and `List<?>.class`,
>   since no such `Class` objects exist. 
>   Only the raw type `List` has a `Class`
>   object that represents its runtime
>   type. It is referred to as
>   `List.class`.

Personally I would do this:

```
public static <C extends Collection<T>,T> SomeWrapper<C> method(
  Class<C> collClass, Class<T> itemClass)
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand that there is no such thing as List<String>.class.  I'm mostly just looking for some sort of syntactic sugar to pass in a List.class object when the type erasure needs to be List<String> in the end.  Unfortunately, I don't control the method (it's a library method in Mockito), so changing the method isn't an option.

Comment: @Brian If you're talking about the `mock()` method, you can only do `List list = mock(List.class)` without a parameterized type. You can choose to cast it to a `List<String>` but this will, as I'm sure you know, generate a warning. I tend to use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation on the method for this. The same issue comes up a lot in JPA. There is no syntactic sugar for this.

Comment: I'm actually using ArgumentCaptor.  As far as I understand, this cast is not allowed (suppress warnings or not).

    ArgumentCaptor<List<String>> predictionCapture = (ArgumentCaptor<List<String>>) ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);